# ADF precopy script to delete before uploading

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

In ADF copy activity,in precopyscript for sink DB, is it possible to execute the precopy script only based on certain condition ? Please let know if any such option.

Comment: Can you ellaborate? What kind of condition are you looking for?

Comment: It's kind of if then, where we check if only certain parameter matches then execute the precopy script to delete data. That parameter can be any pipeline parameter or any look up data retrieved in previous step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "add dynamic content" on the pre-copy script to use the ADF expression language to put logic into the pre-copy. For example use an IF statement.

Comment: Ok will give it a try.

Comment: I see  'if' can be used to return a value based on condition being checked
Can 'if' be used to perform delete from table on certain condition satisfied ? If any example please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the expression in **Pre-copy script** under sink settings in `Copy data` activity.

1. This is my existing data in the table. Here I want to **delete** records with TerritoryID=2 if a condition is matched using `copy data` activity before loading new data.

[image]

2. Below is the expression to use pipeline variables in the expression and using **concat** function in the expression to include variables in with the script.

**Pre-copy script:**

```
@{concat('BEGIN
IF ( ',variables('value'),' = 10 ) 
  delete from [dbo].[sales]
  where convert(varchar,TerritoryID) = ', variables('ID'),';
END')}
```

[image]

3. **Output**: The existing records with TerritoryID = 2 is deleted and new records were inserted.

[image]